# How can I find a random number not located in an array? Want to loop through random numbers until one is found

Tags: javascript

I have a folder containing 10 images (img-1.jpg, img-2.jpg, ...). I currently feature 6 images on a site and I am trying to randomly swap out one of the 6 images with a different one that is not already shown on the page.

I have an array of all of my images (fullList), then I generate and array of the images that are currently shown (currentList).

Where I am having an issue is looping through the currentList array until I find a randomly generated item that is not currently in the currentList array. Then I will chose a random image from the page and change the image.

What I have now:

```
function sawpHeadshots() {
    var fullList = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10];
    var currentList = [];

    $('#headshots li').each(function() {
        currentList.push(parseInt($(this).css('background-image').replace(/\D+/, '')));
    });

    function generateRandom() {
        return fullList[Math.floor(Math.random() * fullList.length)];
    }

    var rand = generateRandom();

    /* not sure how to proceed at this point. */
}
```

Comment: Why not [shuffle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle) your `fullList` and then just draw the 1st, 2nd, 3rd, ...image?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a copy of the array randomly sort it, and remove them from the array when you create it. No need to keep generating random numbers or keeping track what was used.

```
var fullList = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10];
var random = fullList.slice(0).sort(function() {
  return .5 - Math.random();
});

//get value with pop()
var current = random.pop();
```